# Elegant way to map through the object entries

Tags: javascript, oop, mapping

I have an array with some objects and for now I'm kind of repeating the mapping sequence over the constructor as you can see below. What would be the more elegant way to map it? It works, but I feel like I'm missing something and I don't like the way it looks. How could I improve it?

**Initial Structure**

```
[
  {
    id: '1',
    newConfig: {
      array1: [Array],
      array2: [Array],
    },      
  }
]
```

Then I grab the two objects - they are both arrays.

```
  const array1 = response.map((i: any) => i.newConfig.test1);
  const array2 = response.map((i: any) => i.newConfig.test2);
```

And then I map through them as TestsResponse expects two constructors. I don't like the fact that I'm doing that kind of manually and I repeat myself. How could I map it, so I could use the entries in the constructor map?

```
 return new TestsResponse(
            array1.map((c: any) => 
               new Test(
                    String(c.label),
                    String(c.type),
                  )),
             array2.map((c: any) => 
               new Test(
                    String(c.label),
                    String(c.type),
                  )),
        )
```

Comment: Just extract the callback and re-use it?

Comment: but the names of array1 and array2 are unique, how can I make it more generic knowing that cannot change these names?

Comment: I said the callback. that has nothing to do with the arrays: `const myFn = (c: any) =>  new Test( String(c.label), String(c.type), )`

Comment: Oh right, sure I can extract the callback - but is there any way to begin with, so I could map through the unique entries?

Answer (score 0):

This should cover every nesting you have

```js
function TestsResponse() {}

function Test() {}

const data = [{
  id: '1',
  newConfig: {
    array1: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    array2: [3, 4, 5, 6],
  },
}]

new TestsResponse(
  data.map(datum => Object.values(datum.newConfig).map(array => array.map((c) =>
    new Test(
      String(c.label),
      String(c.type),
    )))))
```